# codeigniter pass the parameter before the method in the url?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

im trying to pass parameters into a controler on CodeIgniter but i want the url to be like that :

```
mywebsite/profile/{user_id}/about
```

and not like this :

```
mywebsite/profile/about/{user_id}
```

so it possible please ? and how can we do it ?

Comment: To be sure, profile is the controller name and about is the function?

Comment: I'm not sure, if there's a way to do so. If there is, it would be in the routes.php. try something like `$route['about/(:any)'] = '$1/about'` or the other way around `$route['(:any)/about'] = 'about/$1'`(Not too familiar with the routing system anymore)

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me, I just tested it:

In the routes.php create a new route, that looks like the following:

```
$route['profile/(:any)/about'] = 'profile/about/$1';
```

That will rewrite the URL from e.g. "yoursite.com/profile/about/23" to "yoursite.com/profile/23/about". I assume, that "profile" is your controller and "about" is the function.

Hope, this helps! Didn't test it with an ID that comes from a database, though.

Comment: If your ID's are strictly numbers, you'd be better off using `:num` instead of `:any`.

Comment: Didn't know of a :num, but yeah, that would be the more proper solution